# Javascript functions as Arguments with Arguments

Tags: javascript

What I want is to load multiple files. These files all use the same function to be loaded, only thing different is the file name. This function should return an object. Something like this:

```
var files = [ loadFile("file1.txt"), loadFile("file2.txt"), loadFile("file3.txt") ]; 

// Example function
function loadFile( file_name ) {
    return "loaded file " + file_name;
}
```

But when I run this it loads it directly.

```
var files = [ loadFile, loadFile, loadFile ];

// now please
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    files[i]();
}
```

But this way I can't give it arguments. Now I can create a filler function like this, but I there is probably a better way to do this...

```
function loadFile1() {
    return loadFile( "file1.txt" );
}
```

**If it is possible, how can I load Javascript functions as Arguments with Arguments?**

*done some testing. I am going with [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for the answers, as that is what I was looking for. But I want to mention [Stuart's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1654231/stuart) answer that I definitely will keep in mind for the future use. [MoeSattler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4258088/moesattler) & [vlaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) thank you guys for showing other good ways of doing this!

Comment: Either use `bind()` or make another function or lambda.

Comment: *"but I there is probably a better way to do this"* If you  consider `.bind` to be a better way, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for binding the parameter to the function and call later without parameter.

> The **`bind()`** method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```js
function loadFile( file_name ) {
    return "loaded file " + file_name;
}

var files = [ loadFile.bind(null, "file1.txt"), loadFile.bind(null, "file2.txt"), loadFile.bind(null, "file3.txt") ]; 

files.forEach(function (a) {
    console.log(a());
});
```

Comment: Please beware @flummox, this is a very hacky solution, not idiomatic, and hard to read. Please make sure you get solid JS/programming foundations before you dive in too deep.

Answer (score 6):

Cant you do:

```
// Example function
function loadFile( file_name ) {
    return "loaded file " + file_name;
}

var files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"]; 
for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    loadFile(files[i]);
}
```

Comment: While `bind` is perfectly acceptable (as in my and Nina's answers) this is a **FAR** better solution.  The only case in which `bind` is preferable to this is if the function being applied to each entry in `files` is different.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason anymore to use for loops. map/forEach that stuff :)

Comment: Indeed @MoeSattler but as OP was already using that kind of code, i answered in the same style (no confusion)

Comment: should be `files.map(loadFile)`. `for (i....` is not how to write idiomatic javascript, especially without `var` which makes your `i` global.

Comment: @georg though it's the least of the problems of the above codes. And binding would make it worse.

Answer (score 3):

How about [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

```js
function loadFile( file_name ) {
  return "loaded file " + file_name;
}
const fileNames = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']
const files = fileNames.map(loadFile)

console.log(files)
```

Comment: Your map link goes to the Spanish version.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 is to use what is called a *thunk* - it's simply a function that does not take any arguments and returns a value when executed. It's useful for returning something at a later point. You actually do have an example of that with `loadFile1` but you can generalise it.

```
function loadFileLater(fileName) {
    return function() {
        loadFile( fileName );
    }
}
```

Or using [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
function loadFileLater(fileName) {
    return loadFile.bind(null, fileName);
}
```

Alternatively, you can flip it around and instead of having an array of *functions* that need values, you can have an array of *values* where you execute a function against each

```js
function loadFile( file_name ) {
    return "loaded file " + file_name;
}
var filesNames = [
 "file1.txt",
 "file2.txt",
 "file3.txt",
 "file4.txt"
]

var files = filesNames.map(loadFile)

console.log(files);
```

In your case, you are most likely going to use [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) rather than [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but it's the exact same principle.

Answer (score 1):

[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is going to be your best friend here.

Typically `bind` is used to assign a context to a function (ie: `var myBoundFunc = myFunc.bind(myObj)` will make sure that any references to `this` in `MyFunc` when called via `myBoundFunc` will point to `myObj`), but bind has the added bonus of also being able to store parameters to call `myFunc` with.

So in your case:

```
var files = [ loadFile.bind(this, "file1.txt"), loadFile.bind(this, "file2.txt"), loadFile.bind(this, "file3.txt") ];
```

Where `this` can be any context, and every argument after is used when the resulting function (ie `files[0]()`) is called.